# How do I analyze a site's SSL setup from the command line?

Tags: ssl

SSL Labs has [a web application](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) that checks a site's SSL certificate and setup, and points out problems with them.

I would like to perform similar checks using a CLI tool, e.g. for incorporation in test scripts. Does such a tool exist?

(I'd prefer commands available via APT on Ubuntu, but if there are none, something else would be OK too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest [`testssl.sh`](https://testssl.sh/) (bash script based around openssl) for a similar test suite that you can run locally.